# Qt Serialize audio files and MIME data

Tags: c++, qt, audio

I'm trying to load audio files in my software and be able to create a save file containing the software data with the loaded audio bundled with it (serialized with `QDataStream`).

My first idea was to store the data into a `QByteArray` and later open it with `QBuffer` and play on a `QMediaPlayer` as a `QIODevice`, but as the documentation says:

> If a stream is supplied; media data will be read from it instead of
>   resolving the media source. In this case the media source may still be
>   used to resolve additional information about the media such as mime
>   type. The stream must be open and readable.

The loaded audio may have different kinds of codecs and bitrates, so it would be needed to store this info in a container, as a `QMediaResource` or `QMediaContent` does, but both containers are not serializable.

My other idea was to open a `QByteArray` with a `QFile`, but it doesent seem possible.

So, the question is

> How can an audio file be loaded, serialized and played on a
>   QMediaPlayer correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `QSettings()` to store _codecs_ and _bitrates_ on the fly, Or write your own `JSON` serializer

Comment: QSettings usually store in the registry, i want it to be portable, and modifying the serialization method implies in modification of more than 30 classes, wich i do not want to do kkkkk.  Thanks

Comment: May be you are not favoring the `QSettings` option, I can understand. But `QSettings` is portable.

Comment: I actually didn't mention, but i mean portability about the save file, i want it to be just one file, nothing on the registry, being easily transferable,  just like a game save file, also fast loading and ready for maybe hundreds of sounds,  thanks.